# How to stop a Page from auto-scrolling UP on Mobile devices? (using Blogger Dynamic Views “Mosaic” template)

Tags: blogger, mobile-website, mobile-browser, blogger-dynamic-views

My website is: https://testfnm11.blogspot.com which is based on the Blogger Dynamic Views “Mosaic” template. (I have set the template to display Desktop view on Mobile devices).

The Problem:
On Mobile devices, on an open page, when I scroll down the page and then try to slowly scroll up, the page jumps instantly right to the top. Hence it is impossible to slowly scroll up a page, making it almost impossible to scroll to a particular section of the page.

This problem occurs on all Mobile devices, iOS & Android, as well as on iPad. But this problem is not present on Mac/Safari, where the page scrolls up/down properly. (I have read of people complaining that it happens on Windows PC’s, but I have not verified that myself).

I would be most grateful if someone would suggest a solution to stop a Page auto-scrolling to the top, on mobile devices. (I very much like the Mosaic template, so I am reluctant to change to another template. However as it stands the template is not really usable due to this auto-scrolling issue).

The only change I have made to the HTML code is to replace the original word "classic" with "mosaic" in order to force the template to show Mosaic view on mobile.

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.isMobileRequest'>
        <script expr:src='data:blog.dynamicViewsScriptSrc + &quot;/js/mosaic.js&quot;' type='text/javascript'/>
```

Thank you in advance!

Best wishes,
Firoze Mistry

Comment: @Bassam would you be able to help me with this please? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @firoze, Sure, Blogger dynamic view is a bit complicated as it based on JavaScript. I think you have changed JavaScript tags in the head before to get the Mosaic view on mobile. If so, please add these tags to your question.

Comment: Hello @Bassam, thanks for writing back. The only change I have made to the HTML code is to replace the original word "classic" with "mosaic" in order to force the template to show Mosaic view on mobile.
<b:if cond='data:blog.isMobileRequest'>
        <script expr:src='data:blog.dynamicViewsScriptSrc + &quot;/js/mosaic.js&quot;' type='text/javascript'/>
  PS: I have added this code to my question. Hope this helps you?

Comment: PPS: Aside from the above HTML modification, I have added CSS codes to show full screen photos on mobile, remove View styles, make the Header bar sticky etc. However none of these codes are the cause the issue I am describing. This problem was present even before I added these codes.

Comment: Ok, I found the event function that responsible for the issue. But I cannot override it as the JS code is external. There is a wild solution. We can download the file and place it directly on your template after remove that function.

Comment: I wouldn't mind trying that, since I really like this template and want it to work properly. I will of course back up my template before trying this. So how can we download the file and place it in my template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code that causes the scrolling problem

```
z.onResize=function(){clearTimeout(this.F);$(v).hasClass(u)||(this.F=setTimeout($.proxy(this.G,this),500))};
```

You can download the `mosaic.js` js from `https://www.blogblog.com/dynamicviews/5e2debdf5385ddcf/js/mosaic.js` then remove the code line above and place it between the following script tag

```
<script>
// <![CDATA[

 place the code here

// ]]>
</script>
```

Then, Replace `<script expr:src='data:blog.dynamicViewsScriptSrc + &quot;/js/mosaic.js&quot;' type='text/javascript'/>` with the new code. Please backup your template first.

Comment: I tried the above method, but am getting a error message when I delete the  `<script expr:src='data:blog.dynamicViewsScriptSrc + &quot;/js/mosaic.js&quot;' type='text/javascript'/>` code and paste the modified mosaic.js file in it's place. I Gert this error message: "org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 557; columnNumber: 39; The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference."  What I am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also: between the // <![CDATA[  and // ]]> lines, should I paste the modified mosaic.js code, or should I paste `z.onResize=function(){clearTimeout(this.F);$(v).hasClass(u)||(this.F=setTimeout($.proxy(this.G,this),500))};` code?  And finally, should I delete the all the code between `// <![CDATA[` and `// <![CDATA[`, or leave the code as is and just paste the new code just directly under `// <![CDATA[` ?

Comment: OK, Just replace `<script expr:src='data:blog.dynamicViewsScriptSrc + &quot;/js/mosaic.js&quot;' type='text/javascript'/>` with [this code](https://pastebin.com/bjkFSpqL)

Comment: Bassam, I just discovered that unfortunately the pages still auto-scroll up on iPad - I tested on both standard iPad, and iPad Pro 12.9". However on mobile phone it is perfectly fine. Any solution to stop the auto-scroll on iPad? Sorry to bother you again...

Comment: Blogger doesn't treat tablets as mobile devices. But we can remove the b:if condition to include all devices.

Comment: Okay, how do I remove this b:if condition please?

Comment: After backing up your template. There are 10 tags between `</b:template-skin>` and `</head> ` replace them with [this modified code](https://pastebin.com/xJjZ9w7M)

Comment: Bassam, once again, thank you ever so much!! Apologies for the late reply, I was checking that this works properly on all devices before writing back. I can confirm that this template now works perfectly on all devices.! So to clarify, now all one would need to do to stop the page auto-jump up in a fresh template is to simply follow your last instructions immediately above: There are 10 tags between `</b:template-skin>` and `</head>` , and replace them with this modified code (https://pastebin.com/xJjZ9w7M) . Thanks once again!

Comment: Hi, I have another issue serious with the Mosaic template which I have posted here in the link in this message. I really like this template a lot so I would like to make it work properly. Would you be able to help me with this please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62897581/bug-first-post-page-doesnt-load-fully-in-blogger-dynamic-views-mosaic-theme